How to redirect and prevent WordPress url loading, only by post id
I use the below url structure
/%post_id%/%postname%/
But when I request the /$post_id/, the page loads and I get duplicated content
For example:
https://hamrahmoviez.ir/82267/alien-romulus-2024/
https://hamrahmoviez.ir/82267/
Both URLs return 200
I have two questions:

How I cant redirect /%post_id%/ to /%post_id%/%postname%/
How I prevent return 200 for /%post_id%/ and return 404


Are you sending any traffic to the latter? If not, I wouldn't worry too much about it. The HTML includes a canonical link which the search engines understand. Just don't send traffic to the URLs that you don't want.

To redirect '/%post_id% /' to '/%post_id% /%postname% /', use the '.htaccess' file or server rules. To prevent '/%post_id% /' from providing a 200 status and instead returning a 404, utilize WordPress's 'template_redirect' hook to check for numeric URLs and return 404 if no post has been found.

@MansiJani "To redirect /%post_id%/ to /%post_id%/%postname%/, use the .htaccess file" - that would only work, if they wrote an individual rule for each single post. (You can not add information, that you don't have - the web server has no idea, which post name belongs to which post ID, that requires a look-up in the database.)
